# Designing and Implementing an API that does several steps

Tags: c#, java, oop, c#-4.0, design-patterns

What can be the best design approach? The requirement is to create a simple service interface that does 20-30 different steps. In other words, I have a service class with function DoSomeWork(). And DoSomeWork is going to perform 20-30 steps and if successful return success message and if failed then return exact message of where it failed and why.

```
public class SomeWork :ISomeWorkWork{
public StatusMessage DoSomeWork(){
   //Do Step 1
   //Do Step 2
   //Do Step 3
 }
}
```

The simplest way is to encapsulate all the steps inside private methods and call them inside the DoSomeWork() method. But that is not acceptable, since then the individual steps wont be testable, mock-able. The other way is to create a separate class that'll implment an interface say ISomeWorkService. Then inside the DoSomeWork method get an instance of ISomeWorkService, through an IOC container and invoke the methods for the steps. I was thinking if state pattern fits into this scenario or not. What I need is DoSomeWork should be able to figure out automatically, which step it need to execute and it should either run till the last step or exit if any error is encountered. Any help would be appreciable :)

Comment: Take a look at the [Pipe and Filters](http://www.eaipatterns.com/PipesAndFilters.html) pattern. I think it could be appropriate, and if you need to use the result of each step it's even better.

Comment: thanks @Pierre-Luc Pineault. It's close to what I am looking. But done any example, checked [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38799/Pipeline-and-Yield-in-C)

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault: Don't be shy. Add that as an answer (but elaborate a bit)

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault but it looks to me like that's already what op is doing, no?

Comment: @PeteH: Yes the link implements the Pipe and Filter pattern. But I am scared it'll explode my project with many classes.

Comment: Brikesh, 20-30 steps is an awful lot, I think you may get an explosion whatever approach you take! Do you have any scope to rationalise this? For example five steps, each with four sup-steps? You'll still end up with the same code, just maybe a bit more manageable.

Comment: @PeteH. Thanks for detailed answer and follow. Yo're right it'll explode anyways. I am think using the Pipe-Filter approach, mixed with delegates. But instead of having the functions in separate classes, I'll put them as public functions in one class. And the MessagePipeline will create delegates out them and register. I'll show the exact code snippet shortly and procide a simple function that will execute all the delegates. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm semi-reluctant to suggest this since 20 steps is a lot to contend with (and in fact it might be worth your while trying to do something about this), so things could get messy, but...

One approach you could take is to have some kind of delegate mechanism, which would allow the caller to break into the flow of code and to override the default logic within the step. You could achieve the same effect using events, although I think delegates may be slightly cleaner.

This would allow the caller (which could be a unit test rig) to mock the individual step. Or not.

So, DoSomeWork() would still contain the logic that says, do step 1, now do step 2, now do step 3 etc. but the steps themselves can (but don't have to be) overridden by the caller.

As I say, if you're talking several tens of steps this could become quite messy, but the more I think about it I reckon whatever approach you take which allows you to mock this many steps, is going to be quite messy.

**For example** (assuming you're processing Widgets, and using delegates):

Your "worker" class would look as follows:

```
public delegate Widget StepOneActionDelegate(Widget widget);

public class Worker
{

    public StepOneActionDelegate StepOneAction { get; set; }

    public Worker()
    {
        StepOneAction = RealStepOne;
    }

    public void DoSomeWork()
    {
        Widget widget = new Widget();
        Widget newWidget = StepOneAction(widget);
        // more steps here
    }

    private Widget RealStepOne(Widget widget)
    {
        // Do some real work here
        return widget;
    }
}
```

...while your Test harness could do something like...

```
    void Test()
    {
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        worker.StepOneAction = NewStepOne;
        worker.DoSomeWork();
    }


    Widget NewStepOne(Widget widget)
    {
        // Do some mocking here
        return widget;
    }
```

...and in "real life" you'd say....

```
    void DoItForReal()
    {
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        worker.DoWork();
    }
```

This approach will allow you to mock each step individually if you so wish, but to preserve the structure/functionality of your Worker class as you develop it. It would also allow you to create more specialized Workers going forward, which for example could buy into most of the steps of the original Worker class, but could do their own thing in Steps 5, 9 and 14.